# Using gmaps4rails with Active Admin, no maps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, gmaps4rails

I am trying to get [gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) with [Active Admin](http://activeadmin.info/) in Rails Rails 3.2.8.

I have been trying to follow [this tutorial](http://kalapun.com/blog/2012/05/17/rails-maps-and-activeadmin/) but have needed to adapt it as I am using mysql in my stack.

I am not getting any errors (which might help!) but I am also not getting any maps.

My model (**location**) has the attributes *longitude:float, langitude:float* and *gmaps:boolean*

I have added the following to the locations model, which is different to the tutorial:

```
def location
    [:latitude, :longitude]
end
```

and this to the active admin locations model, also different from the tutorial:

```
f.input :location do |o|
           gmaps("markers" => {data: o.to_gmaps4rails}, "map_options" =>  { auto_zoom: false, zoom: 15 })
     end
```

As far as I can tell (by scanning through the rendered source files) the CSS and JavaScript seem to be loading.

The whole app is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/mildfuzz/aperture_current)

Other that those changes, I think I have stuck to the tutorial.

Comment: I've no experience with active admin, sorry

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever get this solved?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The project is ongoing and I have moved on to other things. I will have to return to this problem. If you do find a solution, please write it up here!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just working on the same problem and seem to have come up with a solution.  If you create a new partial and call it in your active admin model like `form :partial = 'partial_name'`

Then in the partial using the

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @model_name] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input #all your other inputs %>

  <%= f.inputs "Location" do %>
    <%= gmaps("markers" => {data: @model_name.to_gmaps4rails}) %>
    <%= yield :scripts %>
    <%= f.input :latitude %>
    <%= f.input :longtude %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>'
```

You will still need to include the gmaps4rails sprockets in your active admin css and js files.

Comment: I fixed this, but essentially this is what I did.